# Rectangle.X vs Rectangle.Left

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

I see that the `System.Drawing.Rectangle` class has two sets of properties:

- `X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height`
- `Left`, `Top`, `Right`, `Bottom`

The difference between `Width` and `Right` are obvious. But I don't understand the reasoning behind the `Left` and `Top` properties.

Can these be used interchangeably along with `X` and `Y`, or am I missing something obvious? Is there a convention for when I should use which?

Comment: `Top` returns `Y`. (same for left) http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Rectangle.cs,17559e21008f381d

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Left`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Rectangle.cs,192) is purely a wrapper around the `X` property.

The same goes for [`Top`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Rectangle.cs,205) / `Y`.

As noted by [hakononakani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4598879/hakononakani), they are both `readonly` - in order to set the properties you need to use `X` and `Y`.

Comment: Also from the docs: Left and Top are read only, while X and Y have setters.

Comment: it's just so people don't have to use X and Right or Top and Y which would be horrible.

Comment: @hakononakani Good catch.  Will point it out in the answer too.

Comment: Seems like a naming issue that caused the duplication. It's rare to see two things that do exactly the same thing in the .NET framework. Made me sceptical about this one... Thanks, this clears up my confusion.

Answer (score 3):

`Left` only **gets** the x-coordinate. However, `X` **gets or sets** the x-coordinate. 
Same applies to `Top` and `Y`.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same property.

It is there to maintain familiarity with Visual Basic.

Old versions of Visual Basic (including VB6) only used Top and Left property to manipulate positions of controls.

Microsoft source: [Form Positioning for Visual Basic 6.0 Users](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykd2t3th%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> In Visual Basic 6.0, the initial screen location for a form can be set
>   at design time using the Form Layout window or by setting the Left and
>   Top properties in the Properties window. The Left and Top properties
>   can also be set programmatically.

After Microsoft dropped VB6 support and made Visual Basic .NET, Visual Studio included an migration wizard to upgrade old projects to .NET cousins, but that wizard continued to use old properties while converting numeric values of Left and Top. (Twips to .NET Pixels)

Answer (score 0):

```
Rectangle.X = Gets or sets the x-coordinate of the upper-left corner of this Rectangle structure.

Rectangle.left = Gets the x-coordinate of the left edge of this Rectangle structure.
```

Here is the complete guide for [Rectangle Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)